Update system python
Sequoia ships with Python 3.9.something. However, I need a more recent version for some machine learning applications I need to run. Should I really run a separate python installation e.g. with home-brew or can I simply update the system Python - and if so, how? - and use that one (which sounds cleaner)?

Software which is distributed as part of macOS can’t be individually updated, this includes things in /usr/bin. The common approach is to use Homebrew or MacPorts, or just install the version you want from https://python.org.

The python the OP mentions comes from the CLT, not from the OS.  Apple has not shipped a "system" python since Monterey.

@MarcWilson Ah right. But even that one is difficult to update individually.
